# Regex to return different parts if starts with specific string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to return a value from a string if it starts like "P0000000S" but if it doesn't then return another.

For example:

I have this string

> P0000000S521500500015 1TZ003B 3090942 04260
>
> Result: 3090942

As this starts with P0000000S it should return this result: 3090942

But this one

> P3417677S521500500015 1TZ003B 3090942 04260
>
> Result: 3419677

Should return the numbers that are between the first P until the S: 3417677

After reading and investigating I came up with this Regex:

```
(?(?=^P0000000S)^.{29}\s(\w+)\s.{5}$|^P(\d+).{35})
```

Which according to this site where I tested it's working

https://regex101.com/r/aH1vG7/1

Well, I'm trying to use this on a C# APS.NET site that I'm creating but it's not working, I need to clarify that I need to do the IF-THEN-ELSE logic on the Regex because this is a validator for one of a lot of other validators and all the other ones are working.
If it's of any help I use this with Regex.Match function and then cycle the resulting groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Using a regular expression for this kind of logic is definitely the wrong tool for the job (even if it's somehow possible). Just write a simple function that tokenizes the input and determines (based on your rules) which part to return. It'll take less time to write, will be more readable and definitely more maintainable.

Comment: side note : the IF statement is redundant. since if first lookahead fails `(?=` then it will go for the pattern after OR.

Comment: I know that it's easier to use a function but this validation is for a scanning on a production line where I work and it's the only line that has a condition, all the other lines use a regular expression to extract the part number and serial number from different formatted strings.
These regular expressions are put on a database which reads the appropriate validation string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different conditions with lookarounds:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=P0000000S\w+\s\w+\s)\w+|(?<=P)\d+(?=S)");
```

You just need to filter that the result is not 0000000.

Comment: This worked for me although I'll be using the other answer because the already implemented code on the application uses the original string on the group[0] to validate the scanning, but I didn't mentioned this on the original question, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just use two different regexen and fall through if there's no match for the first one.

```
static string PartImInterestedIn(string input)
{
    Match match;
    match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?=^P0000000S)\S+ \S+ (\S+)");
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        match = Regex.Match(input, @"^P(\d+)S");
    }

    return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned I can't do the validation on the C# code because this is an already in use system that validates with regex strings, but the problem is that this is the first case that they have a part number on 2 different probable positions, but thanks anyway for the support.